# Call access functions from Excel without Access 2016 installed on the computer

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Would it be possible to call Access functions from Excel VBA without Access installed on the computer?

I tried this:

```
Sub RunAccessSubLateBinding()

    Dim objAccess As Object
    Dim dbPath As String
    dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database141.accdb"

    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase dbPath

    objAccess.Run "HelloWorld"

End Sub
```

It runs on my PC (which has Microsoft Access installed) but not on users who don't have Access installed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of an application that isn't there.

For Microsoft Access, as a bare minimum, a runtime (free) must be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The big question is why you would want to? "Access" is the GUI to an underlying database engine, and broadly speaking only contains forms and reports. The underlying queries and tables are controled by the engine which is installed by wondows, not Access. So you can manipulate and query databses with Excel, without needing Access, using either ADO or DAO technologies.

Comment: I just need to import data, run function and export data  No need to have thé full application or run Time one. If ADO or DAO allow that. It's ok. By thé way, is thé code above is part of ADO or DAO technologue?

Comment: Your code is using Microsoft COM to allow one program to access another. You want to import data using ADO. There's lots of stuff on that on the web.